# VLAN and WLAN access point configuration. Bridging operation not supported. Looking for alternatives

Tags: wifi, bridge, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I have an old WiFi appliance (air conditioner (AC)) that requires WiFi Protected Setup (WPS) to authenticate. I repurposed an old BT router with WPS, but this has died so I am attempting to configure an RPi 3, model B. It's running "Bookworm" released: 2023-10-10, but I don't particularly care about the version.

My home network is segmented and I have a dedicated VLAN for dodgy home automation devices that's firewalled off from important data.

I wish to be able to access the RPi via a "trusted" management network but isolate the AC (Wi-Fi) traffic on the "dirty" home automation network.

I have successfully configured the RPi as an access point, supporting WPS, but in this config, there are no VLANs and it is entirely on the "dirty" network, meaning I have to change my PC network to the "dirty" network to SSH to the RPi.

In my mind, I need to create something like a [Ubiquity Unifi Access Point](https://eu.store.ui.com/eu/en/pro/category/all-wifi/products/uap-ac-mesh).

I've tried to create a bridge, but that doesn't seem possible and as @Milliways suggests a bridge doesn't segment traffic anyway.

What is the technical name for what I am trying to do, or what search terms should I use?

If anyone has a solution or ideas of things to try, I'd be very grateful if you'd share.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I've updated the question, removing my thought process and failed attempts to try and give it focus and remove conflicting details.

Comment: This question lacks focus, contains so many conflicting details it is unanswerable. You cannot use bridging (which puts devices on 1 segment); you are attempting to mix different networking tools. If you are going to use Bookworm you should use NetworkManager - this is new to the Pi but has been used for decades on Linux.

Comment: @Milliways, sorry about that. I've updated it which I hope gives it focus. Thanks for the info on bridging - obvious when you think about it. I'll look at NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it doesn't answer the question, but I couldn't get it to work with Raspbian directly and I'd spent too much time on it, so I installed OpenWrt. I still had issues, but the OpenWrt community saved the day: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/access-point-with-vlans-on-raspberry-pi/176293